# Rearrange the Xml child node in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

I have problem in rearranging xml data.

I have like this

```
<PolicySummary>
    <InsuredName></InsuredName>
    <PolicyNumber></PolicyNumber>
    <PrevPolicyNumber></PrevPolicyNumber>
    <PolicyState></PolicyState>
    <TotalPremium></TotalPremium>

    <Address></Address>
    <Address1></Address1>
    <City></City>
    <State></State>
    <Zip></Zip>
</PolicySummary>
```

But I want like this

```
 <PolicySummary>
     <InsuredName></InsuredName>
     <PolicyNumber></PolicyNumber>
     <PrevPolicyNumber></PrevPolicyNumber>
     <PolicyState></PolicyState>
     <TotalPremium></TotalPremium>
     <MailingAddress>
         <Address></Address>
         <Address1></Address1>
         <City></City>
         <State></State>
         <Zip></Zip>
     </MailingAddress>
</PolicySummary>
```

I want mailing address node should contain address ,address1,city, state, zip  can any one help. I tried many way like append child , insert after but nothing is worked

I tried to take the node and insert the mailing address and append it

```
XmlDocument policysummary = new XmlDocument();

XmlNode copynode = policysummary.ImportNode(
   xmlautoDocument.SelectSingleNode("PolicySummary/TotalPremium"), true);

XmlNode premium = policysummary.SelectSingleNode("TotalPremium");
XmlNode addressss = policysummary.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element,
                                            "Mailingaddress", null);
XmlNode root2 = policysummary.DocumentElement;

premium.InsertAfter(addressss, premium);
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried so that we can help you understand what's wrong, rather than just saying it doesn't work. Also, if you can use LINQ to XML instead of XmlDocument, that would make things simpler.

Comment: I Took the data directly from SQl and converted into XML. But i want the rearranged  out put

Comment: So what does your current code give as output? (Also, please format your code - it's all over the place at the moment.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `XDocument` instead of `XmlDocument`:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString)

var root = xDoc.Element("PolicySummary");
var totalPremium = root.Element("TotalPremium");

//get all values you want to put in mailing address
var address = root.Element("Address");
//...

var mailingAddress = new XElement("MailingAddress");
mailingAddress.Add(address);

//Add mailing address after total premium
totalPremium.AddAfterSelf(mailingAddress);

//Remove all values you inserted in mailing address
address.Remove();

//If you want to save it somewhere
xDoc.Save(fileName);
```